# Bulkify SOSL query in loop

Tags: apex, sosl, bulkification

I'm trying to build a process which looks up a matching account for a lead, given a cleaned email or website.

The issue I'm facing is that this could be run against 1000 or 10k leads at once and the query within the loop is going to cause some issues.

What can I do to bulkify this so that I don't hit REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED errors?

HelperClass

```
public class LeadTriggerHelper {

    Public static void UpdateLead(List<Lead> Leads){
        ldupdate = new List<Lead>();

        for(Lead ld1 : Leads){
            String accountName;

            if(ld1.cleaned_email__c != null && ld1.cleaned_email__c != ''){
                accountName = ld1.cleaned_email__c;
            }//if

            else if(ld1.cleaned_website__c != null && ld1.cleaned_website__c != ''){
                accountName = ld1.cleaned_website__c;                
            }//else

            List<List<Account>> acc2 = [FIND :accountName IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Account LIMIT 1];

            if(acc2.size()>0){
                ld1.Account_Lookup__c = acc2[0][0].Id;
            }//if
        }//for   
    }//UpdateLead
}//LeadTriggerHelper
```

Trigger

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    if(trigger.isBefore){
        If(trigger.isUpdate){
            for (Lead lead : Trigger.new){
                Lead oldLead = Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id);
                if (oldLead.Trigger_Account_Update__c != lead.Trigger_Account_Update__c){
                    LeadTriggerHelper.UpdateLead(trigger.new);                        
                }//if
            }//for
        }//isUpdate
    }//isBefore
}//Trigger
```

Answer (score 5):

To bulkify the method,  SOSL should be outside of for loop.

Correct syntax for joining field is (refer [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples.htm)):

> FIND {"Joe Smith" OR "Joe Smythe"}
>
> IN Name Fields
>
> RETURNING lead(name, phone), contact(name, phone)

So,

- create `List<String> lstName = new List<String>();`
- add values to `lstName`
- use `String str = String.join(lstName, ' OR ');`

And, finally use the list into SOSL as

```
FIND :str IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Account LIMIT 1
```

So possible changes will be as follows

```
public class LeadTriggerHelper {

    Public static void UpdateLead(List<Lead> Leads){
        ldupdate = new List<Lead>();

        List<String> lstName = new List<String>();
        for(Lead ld1 : Leads){
            String accountName;
            if(ld1.cleaned_email__c != null && ld1.cleaned_email__c != ''){
                accountName = ld1.cleaned_email__c;
                lstName.add(accountName);
            }//if
            else if(ld1.cleaned_website__c != null && ld1.cleaned_website__c != ''){
                accountName = ld1.cleaned_website__c; 
                lstName.add(accountName);
            }//else
        }//for 
        
        String str = String.join(lstName, ' OR ');
        
        List<List<Account>> acc2 = [FIND :str IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Account LIMIT 1];

            if(acc2.size()>0){
                // perform your desired operation.
            }//if
            
    }//UpdateLead
}//LeadTriggerHelper
```

Comment: Your code only updates ld1, I may need to update 10,000 leads.

Comment: I haven't done any changes to updates. he has to write this logic

Comment: @kmomo, if my answer solves your purpose then accept this, so that others may find this useful

Comment: This is great thanks! Is there any limit on the number of "OR" joining fields that can be used...?

Comment: I think no limit, I think Salesforce standard query character limit is imposed here

Comment: Thanks! Found them here for reference: [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm)