# Bulkify SOSL Invocable Apex

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I have the following invocable class. It currently functions as I would like (updating the Interaction__c record with a ContactId that is found using a conditional SOSL query and subsequent regular expression on first name fields and last name). However, the issue I am running into is too many SOSL queries: 21.

I assumed that everything was already bulkified, since it is a list of interaction__c records being passed into the class. However, that does not appear to be the case. How can I bulkify this class to pass in the list of interaction__c records, return a list of interaction__c records to update so that I can update them in the flow that calls it. The reason I would like to do that is it keeps the class more flexible and easier to implement in other flows. Below is my script:

```
public class InteractionContactMatcher {

    public class InteractionInput {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true) public String FirstName;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true) public String LastName;
        @InvocableVariable public String Email;
        @InvocableVariable public String MobilePhone;
        @InvocableVariable public String HomePhone;
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Match Interaction to Contacts' description='Finds the first matching contact based on Interaction data.')
    public static List<Id> matchContacts(List<InteractionInput> inputs) {
        List<Id> matchedContactIds = new List<Id>();

        for (InteractionInput input : inputs) {
            List<Contact> potentialMatches = new List<Contact>();

            if (input.Email != null && input.Email != '') {
                potentialMatches.addAll(findMatchingContactsByEmail(input.Email));
            } else {
                potentialMatches.addAll(findMatchingContactsByPhone(input.MobilePhone, input.HomePhone));
            }

            // Filter contacts based on sanitized names and get the first match
            Id matchedContactId = filterContactsByNamesAndReturnFirstMatch(potentialMatches, input.FirstName, input.LastName);
            matchedContactIds.add(matchedContactId);
        }
        return matchedContactIds;
    }

    private static List<Contact> findMatchingContactsByEmail(String email) {
        List<List<SObject>> searchResults = [FIND :email IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, FirstName, LastName, Banner_First_Name__c, Preferred_First_Name__c,Interaction_First_Name__c, Import_First_Name__c)];
        return (List<Contact>)searchResults[0];
    }

    private static List<Contact> findMatchingContactsByPhone(String mobilePhone, String homePhone) {
        List<String> phones = new List<String>();
        if (mobilePhone != null && mobilePhone != '') phones.add(mobilePhone);
        if (homePhone != null && homePhone != '') phones.add(homePhone);
        String phoneSearchString = String.join(phones, ' OR ');

        List<List<SObject>> searchResults = [FIND :phoneSearchString IN PHONE FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, FirstName, LastName, Banner_First_Name__c, Preferred_First_Name__c, Interaction_First_Name__c, Import_First_Name__c)];
        return (List<Contact>)searchResults[0];
    }

    private static Id filterContactsByNamesAndReturnFirstMatch(List<Contact> contacts, String firstName, String lastName) {
        String sanitizedInputName = sanitize(firstName) + sanitize(lastName);

        for (Contact c : contacts) {
        if (c.Banner_First_Name__c != null && sanitizedInputName.equals(sanitize(c.Banner_First_Name__c + c.LastName))) {
            System.debug(sanitize('c.Banner_First_Name__c MATCH ' + c.Banner_First_Name__c + c.LastName));
            return c.Id;
        } else if (c.Preferred_First_Name__c != null && sanitizedInputName.equals(sanitize(c.Preferred_First_Name__c + c.LastName))) {
            System.debug(sanitize('Preferred_First_Name__c MATCH ' + c.Preferred_First_Name__c + c.LastName));
            return c.Id;
        } else if (c.FirstName != null && sanitizedInputName.equals(sanitize(c.FirstName + c.LastName))) {
            System.debug(sanitize('FirstName MATCH ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName));
            return c.Id;
        } else if (c.Import_First_Name__c != null && sanitizedInputName.equals(sanitize(c.Import_First_Name__c + c.LastName))) {
            System.debug(sanitize('Import_First_Name__c MATCH' + c.Import_First_Name__c + ' ' + c.LastName));
            return c.Id;
        } else if (c.Interaction_First_Name__c != null && sanitizedInputName.equals(sanitize(c.Interaction_First_Name__c + c.LastName))) {
            System.debug(sanitize('Interaction_First_Name__c MATCH' + c.Interaction_First_Name__c + ' ' + c.LastName));
            return c.Id;            
        }
      }
        System.debug('No Matches');
        return null; // No match found
    }

    private static String sanitize(String value) {
        if (value == null) return '';
        return value.replaceAll('[^A-Za-z]', '').toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently doing one SOSL query for each `InteractionInput`. That is why you are hitting the SOSL limit.

You can bulkify the query by using `OR` in the query, as explained here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/173806/17819